# Вывести Число Пелля C#

Tags: c#

Вывести заданное число Пелля. Необходимо сделать двумя методами.

1. Метод итерации.(циклом и т.д)
2. Метод рекурсии.

Формула числа Пелля[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: с чем именно возникла проблема?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Сделайте. Не вижу препятствий.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как формула рекурсивная, рекурсивный вариант кода составляется интуитивно:

```
double Q(int n){
    if (n == 0) return 2;
    if (n == 1) return 2;
    
    return 2*Q(n-1)+Q(n-2);
}
```

При итерационном подходе, на каждой итерации цикла вычисляется следующее значение, на основе предыдущих двух:

```
double Q(int n){
    double a = 2;
    double b = 2;
    
    for(int i=1; i<n; i++){
        var tmp = a;
        a = b;
        b = 2*a + tmp;
    }

    return b;
}
```